# Use one Function for the mutliple Buttons & Values

Tags: c#, wpf

I am programming an application to get my color management done in a better way.

Therefore I am using WPF and C#. Now I have created 5 Rectangles that should display the color entered underneath in a Textbox. They are updated with the correct color when a button is clicked. The HEX value of the textbox can also be copied by clicking another button on the bottom. 
Now, here's what I have had until now and it works fine for one Button:

[image]

(a picture so that you can imagine what I mean.)

```
    private void CmdBtn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Rectcolor1 collects the value from the textbox
        string RectColor1;
        RectColor1 = TxbRect1.Text;

        //converts the value into hexcode
        Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(RectColor1);
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(color);

        //displays the value by changing the rectangle's color
        Rectangle1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
```

This is what happens when you click the button on the top ("Aktualisieren").
But this works for one button only and I don't want to paste this 4 times.
Is there a better way of writing this code without copy and pasting the whole code several times?

Comment: Can you please provide the XAML source for this Page/Window, or at least these buttons?

Comment: There's a good chance this can be greatly simplified with an ItemsControl and a DataTemplate, but you need to post the XAML for this.

Comment: I think a listbox. You will want to select which rectangle you're working with. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btn1" Click="CmdBtn1_Click />
<Button x:Name="btn2" Click="CmdBtn1_Click />
<!-- Same Click values for all buttons -->
```

Then in the handler method, you can find out which one was pressed via the `sender` parameter. You need to cast it to `Button`.

```cs
var button = sender as Button;
var name = button.Name; // etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sender.Name or sender.Content to determine which button was clicked.